# counting by inclusion exclusion

Tags: dynamic-programming, bitmask

anybody  please  help  me in figuring out the bitmasking used in candles counting problem on hackerrank (inclusion-exclusion principle approach)
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/candles-2
i am not able to clearly get whats being written in the editorial code.
you can open the editorial for full code

```
int res = 0;
for(int mask = 0; mask < (1 << K); mask ++){
    memset(ft, 0, sizeof ft);
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if((mask >> (C[i] - 1)) & 1){
            dp[i] = 1 + query(H[i] - 1); // BIT Query function
            madd(tmp, dp[i]);
            update(H[i], dp[i]); // BIT update function
        }
    }
    if(__builtin_popcount(mask) % 2 == K % 2){
        madd(res, tmp);
    } else {
        madd(res, mod - tmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I could make out of it from the code you posted-

**1)**`if((mask >> (C[i] - 1)) & 1)` checks if the color of `i`th candle's color was already there or not (*assuming mask is used to store colors already used as there is no metion in code)*

**2)**`query(H[i] - 1)`returns the number of subsequences can be formed from all previous candles as they all will be colorful as the current candle is first one having repeating color so if it is excluded we get 'colorful subsequences'.

**3)**`update(H[i], dp[i]);`is used to remove all candles that are not requried.

Example- If our sequence has following colors in order - 2 3 1 4 5 6 1 7 8 
then when we reach at second '1' the stored colors in array will only be 4 5 6 1 that is '2 3 1' will be removed and '7 8' are to be read.

**4)**`madd(tmp, dp[i]);` not sufficient data in ur code *sorry*.

**5)**`__builtin_popcount(mask)` counts number of ones in mask.